# Visualizing relation between two objects using R and export to HTML

Tags: r, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I am using R to visualize relation between, say, 5-6 different nodes. Now, a graph is probably the best way to do it. The issue is, the edges are way too many. There can be a hundred edges between two vertexes. That makes the graph look very clumsy. I want the edge name to be displayed. With a hundred edge name being displayed, they overlap over each other and hence not comprehensible.
So, I have two questions-

1. Is there any other way in which I can represent the data? Some kind of chart probably?
2. I want to export the final output to HTML, which uses d3.js or any other similar library, keeping the edge name and a few other similar information intact. What will be the best plugin to use in that case?

I am using the igraph library to create the graph in R.
I also tried using the networkD3 library to export it to an HTML and make it interactive.

```
graph <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed = TRUE, vertices = vertex)
plot(graph, edge.label = E(graph)$name)
wc <- cluster_walktrap(graph)
members <- membership(wc)
graph_d3 <- igraph_to_networkD3(graph, group = members)
graph_forceNetwork <- forceNetwork(Links = graph_d3$links, Nodes = graph_d3$nodes, 
         Source = 'source',
         Target = 'target', 
         NodeID = 'name',
         Group = 'group',
         zoom = TRUE,
         fontSize = 20)
```

Right now, it is a graph with only two vertex and about 60-70 edges between them. So, I did not use any particular layout.

Comment: I couldn't find any way in which I could visually represent the data. May be I'm lacking in that area. So, I went for a tabular representation instead. I'm using  the DT package to generate an HTML table, with search/export to pdf/excel facilities.

Comment: What about collapsing the edges to a single edge and weighting the line by the frequency?  Pretty much becomes a sankey diagram at that point

Comment: I thought about it. The frequency is same for all the edges, they are unique. It is the name of the edge that matters here.

Comment: Have you thought of a visualization like [BioFrabric](http://www.biofabric.org/)?  It has been implemented in R by timelyportfolio [here](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/RBioFabric)